# How to keep an NSArray available when switching to other view controller

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Hi in VC1 I have an NSMutableArray displaying results. I want to keep that array alive even when users clicks to a different tab (so they don't have to search again) until the user searches again.

I have a strong pointer to it, but it seems to unload when I leave the view.

Not much code to show (_resultsArray is set from a previous controller using delegates, so it loads with the results already)

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _resultsTableView.dataSource=self;
        _resultsTableView.delegate=self;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    }
//then standard tableview delegate methods...
```

This code is to try to figure out how to segue tab bar to share info.
(in prepareforsegue)

Currently in Search VC. Now I have results I want to give to resultsIndexVC. The code below attempts this.
This is placed in current (search VC) prepare for segue.

```
ResultsIndexViewController* vc = [[ResultsIndexViewController alloc] init];
        UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc = (ResultsIndexViewController *)[[tbc customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
        vc.SearchDelegate=self;//crash here (normally works if using regular segue)
        vc.resultsArray = _temporaryResultsArray;
        vc.originalQuery=_queryArray;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you making a new instance of VC1 when you go back to it?

Comment: Why dont you keep that `NSMutableArray` in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: added some code (nothing to show really, results are loaded from a previous screen using delegates)

Comment: VC1 is loaded when user tabs (tabbar). As far as I'm aware that doesn't load VC1 again.

Comment: I try to keep the app delegate empty, and localize everything (using that logic I would just create a globalarray)

Comment: Im mostly looking for something that says retain X object after view disappears

Comment: You don't need that. If you're using a tabBar controller, and you have a strong pointer to your array in one of the content controllers, then it shouldn't be deallocated when you switch back and forth. If it is, then you're doing something wrong, and you need to provide more information about how your app is set up.

Comment: I am loading the second VC using a segue (I know its wrong and I thing thats the problem), I am trying to figure out how to share the data between the two VCs. Currently I am using a protocol delegate in prepareforsegue. Any suggetions on how to do it?  I am posting the code I kind of gathered so far.

Comment: I have no idea what the second VC is in the context of your question. You need to edit your question to fully describe your app's structure.

Comment: Ok, added the code for the prepareforsegue and a brief summary at the top providing context and needed result

Comment: This really doesn't fully describe your app. What is VC1? Is it one of the tabs? What is SearchVC, is it also one of the tabs? Are all the controllers in the app embedded in the tab bar controller? If you're switching between tabs, you don't want to do a segue (but I'm not sure that's what you're trying to so).

Comment: vc1 = tab1  vc2 = tab2 .  each tab has a nav controller with VCs after that. VC1 - Search, get an array of results. (tab 1) || VC2 - display those results (tab 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that I was pushing a VC. Instead I used the tabbar (which doesnt release the object when switching tabs)